# NodeJS could not connect to MYSQL latest version inside Docker Container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

NodeJS cannot connect to MySQL latest version or either 8 onwards and encountered following error message:

`ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.2:3306`

**Here is my docker-compose file**

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  db:
      build: ./db
      networks:
        - ppshein
      environment:
          - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      healthcheck:
          test: "exit 0"
  node:
    build: ./app
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - ppshein
networks:
  ppshein:
```

**Here is db Dockerfiles**

```
FROM mysql:5
COPY init_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**init_db.sql**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database_docker;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on database_docker.*
TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'ppshein123456'
WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

**NodeJS Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:9.10.1
ENV NODE_ENV=docker
COPY ./ /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www/
RUN yarn install && yarn add sequelize-cli -g
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "docker" ]
```

Config.json

```
"docker": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "ppshein123456",
    "database": "database_docker",
    "host": "db",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "logging": false
}
```

But everything is working file when I've changed to `FROM mysql:5` but `FROM mysql` or `FROM mysql:8`, I've encountered above error I've mentioned. Please let me know which kind of configuration do I need to miss it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way to fix that authentication issue. I need to add following command `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` and `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ppshein123456` on `docker-compose` file.

```
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
restart: always
ports:
    - 3306:3306
environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ppshein123456
    - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8 be default uses a new SHA256 encryption for password that your connector probably does not use.  You can update your connector to one that understands SHA256 or change the password on the account being used to one using MySQL Native Password (the older password default)

Comment: Could you suggest some example of that one?

Comment: CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';